# Rails Searching calculated fields using metasearch and metawhere

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, meta-where

Has anyone been able to find a way to search a calculated field using metawhere or metasearch in rails 3? I can search any field but calculated fields. There has to be a way. For anyone not familiar with metasearch or metawhere here is a railscast.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/251-metawhere-metasearch

Comment: Do you mean fields that are not stored in the database and defined in the model instead?

Comment: yes, please explain what you mean by calculated?

Comment: by calculated fields, do you mean virtual parameters defined in model, calculated from database table columns? I dont think u can search those using these gems for that, as the search will ultimately break down to database level.

Comment: I do mean fields that are defined in the model. They are actual stored fields in my database, but I have a method in the model that is populating it with the product of several other fields. Is there any way to search on those? I know they can be sorted in the controller by using the below statement in the controller @user = User.find(:all).sort_by(&:age)  - in this case, age could be date.today - birthday

Answer (score 1):

Metawhere (now Squeel) extends ActiveRecord's implementation of Arel which is a SQL generator. That means it will turn some statement in SQL e.g :

```
@user.order("birthday").to_sql #=> SELECT users.* FROM users ORDER BY birthday
```

When you do `User.find(:all).sort_by(&:age)`  you are working on a the result of find(:all),  an Array, and the sorting is done in Ruby with Enumerable which is slower and has *nothing to do with the database*.

So no, you cannot use Metawhere on

```
def age
  date.today - birthday
end
```

unless you store the result in the database.

**However** you can use the SQL statements like COUNT AVG MAX etc with GROUP and HAVING to do calculation directly on the database.

`User.select("users.*, COUNT(user_id) AS vote_num").joins(:votes).group("user_id")`